# Visual Studio 2012 Won't Load Debug Symbols (While VS 2010 Will)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

This seemingly simple problem has been driving me nuts for two hours. I want to attach a debugger to an app but VS 2012 refuses to load symbols from its PDB file. It works without a problem in VS 2010. The PDB is of the same name as the .EXE and located in the same folder.

This is a screenshot from VS2012:

[image: Attaching debugger from VS 2012]

And this is a screenshot from VS2010:

[image: Attaching debugger from 2010]

As you can see everything looks OK on both screens. However, this is another screenshot from 2012:

[image]

And this one is from 2010:

[image]

It's an exact same process.

It took me an hour of googling, searching and banging my head against a wall to try in VS 2010 and to find out that everything works well there. At first I was convinced I was doing something wrong.

> **Binary was not built with debug information.**

Huh?? There is a PDB file, what *other* debug information it needs? It was *obviously* built with debug information since 2010 doesn't complain at all and I've debugged what I wanted just fine.

The app being debugged is compiled in VB6 (as in classic, legacy VB, not VB.NET).

Any hint, comment or question is welcome...

Comment: Hmm, what could have changed in the past 17 years?   Well, a brand spanking new debugging engine in VS2012 would be one.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General, "Use managed compatibility mode" checkbox might work.

Comment: @Hans did you mean "Managed C++ Compatibility Mode"? It was checked by default and un-checking it unfortunately didn't change anything. I've also restarted VS just in case, same problem persists.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't be surprised that something compiled under VB6 isn't "debuggable" under VS 2012. I'm just so used to it that it just didn't hit me but you are probably right.